# Push Notifications for Apple Watch

Tags: push-notification, certificate, apple-watch, apn

From what I've understood (which could be completly wrong and therefore this post will make no sense), I need to create separate APP Id's in my developer portal for my Watch app/extension.

I did that, and I now have 3 app ID's and their complete related set of provisioning profiles up and running.

The archive works fine and I'm about to submit but, I see that because there is an app ID, I can link a PUSH Certificate (apn). Since the Apple Watch doesn't really get notified, but the phone does, do I really need to create specific certificates for the apple Watch ? And use their related .p12 wherever I would need them (parse.com for example) ?

Or can I simply ignore that and keep the regular phone certificates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have push notifications set up properly for your iPhone app, they will be delivered to the Watch automatically. You don't need to set up any separate certificates.

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1

Additionally, I have deployed a number of apps already and have first-hand experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; if you could provide a link from somewhere "reliable" (not that you aren't, I'd just like to make sure) that'd be awesome. I couldn't find such information in the apple doc

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a link to the docs. Check the first few paragraphs discussing notifications.